# Trouble sending data to SendGrid API using Netlify Functions in React.js (SOLVED)

Tags: reactjs, email, sendgrid, netlify, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm working on a React app that integrates SendGrid for email automation. To achieve this, I'm using Netlify Functions to interact with the SendGrid API (https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/email-integration/). The problem is that despite having configured the Netlify function and React app to make the API request, the data isn't being successfully sent to SendGrid's API. I'm not receiving any error messages, and the function executes without issues. When deploying locally the email is being sent to subscriber's email address, but that's as far as I get.

I've reviewed the Netlify function logs, and there are no error messages or indications of any issues. I've checked the network tab in the browser's developer tools, and the request to the Netlify Function is successful. And I've verified that my SendGrid API key is correctly set as an environment variable in Netlify. My SendGrid account is also verified, so that shouldn't be causing any problems. At the moment I'm expecting that when a subscribers submits the subscription form, the Netlify Function would be triggered, and the subscriber's email should be added to the SendGrid contact list.
Here's the function code:

```
import type { Handler } from "@netlify/functions";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const handler: Handler = async function(event) {
  if (event.body === null) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify("Payload required"),
    };
  }

  const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body) as {
    subscriberName: string;
    subscriberEmail: string;
    inviteeEmail: string;
  };

  await fetch(`https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer apiKey123`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "contacts":[
        {
        "email": requestBody.subscriberEmail,}
      ]
      }),
    })

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify("Subscribe email sent!"),
  };
};

export { handler };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I managed to find the problem on my own. I will post it here in hope that someone else who encounters similar issues will not need to spend days trying to figure out what's wrong :)
So, basically I needed to add "cookies" property

```
  const cookie = event.headers["Cookie"] || event.headers["cookie"];
```

and define headers with and without cookies

```
const headersWithoutCookie = {
Authorization: `Bearer apiKey123`,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',};
const headers = {
...headersWithoutCookie,
cookie: cookie || '',};
```

and after that just add headers in the function

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts`, {
headers,
method: "PUT",
```